# Why don't CMake COMPILER_DEFINITIONS propagate to subdirectories?

Tags: c++, cmake

Per [the set_directory_properties docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_directory_properties.html), properties set on the directory are supposed to propagate to subdirectories:

> Set a property for the current directory and subdirectories.

Per [the supported properties documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#directory-properties), COMPILE_DEFINITIONS is a property supported by directories.

Given this, why doesn't COMPILE_DEFINITIONS for a directory propagate to subdirectories in the following example?

## Sample Project File Structure

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- sub
   -CMakeLists.txt
   -main.cpp
```

## File Contents

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(cmake_sandbox)
add_subdirectory(sub)
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS SHOW_MESSAGE=1)
```

Sub CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #define A_LOCAL_MESSAGE
    #ifdef A_LOCAL_MESSAGE
    #pragma message("A local message!")
    #else
    #pragma message("No local message!")
    #endif

    #ifdef SHOW_MESSAGE
    #pragma message("A message!")
    #else
    #pragma message("No message!")
    #endif
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

## Testing

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
$ rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j && sub/hello
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/caleb/src/cmake-sandbox/build
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 50%] Building CXX object sub/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/caleb/src/cmake-sandbox/sub/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/caleb/src/cmake-sandbox/sub/main.cpp:8:36: note: #pragma message: A local message!
  #pragma message("A local message!")
                                    ^
/home/caleb/src/cmake-sandbox/sub/main.cpp:16:31: note: #pragma message: No message!
  #pragma message("No message!")
                               ^
[100%] Linking CXX executable hello
[100%] Built target hello
Hello, World!
```

If the COMPILE_DEFINITION set at the root level had propagated as expected, the second pragma output would have changed to "A message!" case. Why isn't this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`add_subdirectory` causes CMake to enter the subdirectory and process the CMakeLists.txt file in there *before* processing the directives that follow `add_subdirectory`.

If you want those settings picked up you need to set them before you recurse into a subdirectory.

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS SHOW_MESSAGE=1)
add_subdirectory(sub)
```